# Retrieving data from NSDictionary and putting it into an NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am trying to get a value from an NSDictionary and put it into an NSMutableArray. Here's some of my code for example.

```
- (IBAction)pressedButton:(id)sender {
    NSInteger numberOfResults = 3;
    NSString *searchString = @"EMINEM";

    NSString *encodedSearchString = [searchString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *finalSearchString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=%@&entity=song&limit=%li",encodedSearchString,(long)numberOfResults];

    NSURL *searchURL = [NSURL URLWithString:finalSearchString];
    dispatch_queue_t iTunesQueryQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    dispatch_async(iTunesQueryQueue, ^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:searchURL options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];

        if (data && !error) {

            NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
            NSArray *array = [JSON objectForKey:@"results"];
            NSMutableArray *arrayTracks;
            for (NSDictionary *bpDictionary in array) {
                [arrayTracks addObject:[bpDictionary objectForKey:@"trackName"]];
                // _author = [bpDictionary objectForKey:@"trackName"];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    self.label.text = [arrayTracks objectAtIndex:0];
                    // self.label2.text = _author;
                    // NSLog(@"%@", [array objectAtIndex:0]);
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see from the above, it does not properly put the value into the array. If I set the `_author` to `[bpDictionary objectForKey:@"trackName"]` then it does work, but it goes through it all and sets the label as the last in the array. The above code outputs nothing (null).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leverage foundation to your advantage, there's no need to iterate the array manually.

To get an array of track names you can simply use `valueForKey:` or `valueForKeyPath:`

```
NSArray *trackNames = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"results.trackName"];
```

That being said, I urge you to perform networking tasks with networking API. You should never be using `NSData` to retrieve JSON. Stick to NSURLSession, it's cleaner and designed for networking tasks.

```
[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:itunesSearchURL
                             completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            // now you have a properly downloaded JSON
           //and you even have access to the URL response headers and any errors.
}]resume];
```

### Edit

As an aside, you never initialize your array of `trackNames` so calling addObject on a nil value will have no effect.

Comment: Thanks! Can you help out on this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26826688/how-do-i-save-an-m4a-from-web-and-copy-to-clipboard