# How do I save an .m4a from web and copy to clipboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, nsdata, mp4

I am downloading a .m4a from a url on an iOS device then copying to clipboard. So far, this is what I have:

```
NSArray *preview = [JSON valueForKey:@"results.previewUrl"];
NSURL *previewUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[preview objectAtIndex:0]];
NSData *previewData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:previewUrl];
```

How do I copy that .m4a to clipboard? I believe there is a way to copy .mp3s and .mp4s (.m4a is same as .mp4).
results.previewUrl is http://a281.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/119/Music/v4/f1/7b/d6/f17bd6e3-55c0-b7e0-9863-bc522900e950/mzaf_5153970109972844579.aac.m4a

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are interested in is [UIPasteBoard](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uipasteboard_class/index.html). It seems to fit your needs. Check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/codeswimmer/4437535) for some examples